# MS Office Interop - can't release references to RCW

Tags: c#, .net, com, office-interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint in my app to control presentation SlideShow. I can connect to PowerPoint using code

```
PowerPointApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application;
```

and all works ok, but I can't release refereces (after SlideShow ends and PowerPoint was CLOSED) using

```
 Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(PowerPointApp);
```

This call still throws an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B196B286-BAB4-101A-B69C-00AA00341D07}' failed due to the following error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).
```

I tried to wrap both methods (GetActiveObject and FinalReleaseComObject) into:

```
 App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ ... });`
```

to ensure that both methods are called from same thread, but I got same exception.

I also tried to release references when PowerPoint is still runnig - in this case, references to RCW are released without exception (but I need to release these referencers after PowerPoint is closed)

Comment: There are a gazillion posts about this already, [here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReleaseComObject instead of the FinalReleaseComObject method. The [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article states the following:

> Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Office/PowerPoint object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

It is related to Outlook, but the same principles can be applied to any Office application.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me - still same problem.