# Excel process shows back up after closing excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I am opening an excel file from my winform using:

```
Dim xlsApp3 As Excel.Application
Dim xlsWB3 As Excel.Workbook
xlsApp3 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp3.Visible = True
xlsWB3 = xlsApp3.Workbooks.Open("C:\myfile.xlsm")

Try
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsWB3)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsApp3)
    xlsWB3 = Nothing
    xlsApp3 = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    xlsWB3 = Nothing
    xlsApp3 = Nothing
Finally
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
End Try
```

When I look at my task manager, it closes the process, but as soon as I close the excel application window that I open, the process comes back? If I close my whole winform application, thats when the excel process closes. Is the application holding on to the process in memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean up Excel Interop Objects with IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't access anything unmanaged with two dots like you did in

```
xlsApp3.Workbooks.Open
```

The Workbooks object is opened behind the scenes but .NET doesn't know about it and it can't clean it up properly.

Instead, you need to make a .NET reference to Workbooks, and the GC will clean everything up for you. Your entire code snippet can be reduced to this

```
Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application()
Dim xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
Dim xlBook = xlBooks.Open("C:\myfile.xlsm")
xlApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: There is no need for Dot Rules.  The CLR is not broken.  [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/2592875)

Comment: The excel process does not come back anymore after closing the workbook.

Comment: @TnTinMn I know all about Hans' posts regarding Interop. This works though.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines:

```
xlsWB3.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)        
xlsApp3.Quit
```

Comment: I can't close and quit it because I don't know when the user is done modifying the excel workbook that was opened.

Comment: Then why do you need interop at all? Just shellexecute the file:  ShellExecute("C:\myfile.xlsm")

Comment: I need the workbook to open on it's own instance because i have other workbooks opened at the same time, and the way the workbook closes is closing the whole window thus it will close the other workbooks which i do not need it to do.