# C# memory leak using exel and interop COM

Tags: c#, excel, com, office-interop, com-interop

UPDATED 3/12/20.  I am struggling with a problem where the Excel application is not releasing following my function call below.  I'm not sure what references I'm screwing up but I assume I'm somehow leaving a reference to the application because I see multiple Excel processes in my task manager as the program runs, not to mention large amounts of memory use that don't improve with GC.  Thoughts?

```
    static void ParseExcel(string file, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range rng = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        double colCount = rng.Columns.Count;
        double rowCount = rng.Rows.Count;
        //iterate over the rows and columns
        //start on row 2 since row 1 is column headers
        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            string companyName = "";
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //write the value to the console
                if (rng.Cells[i, j] != null && rng.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                {
                    string tst = rng.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                    switch (j)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            companyName = tst;
                            break;
                    }
                }    //end of column
            }//end of row
            //write to database
            string sql = "insert into dbo.company( ";
            sql += DBI(companyName) + ")";
            Console.WriteLine("sql = " + sql);
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);            
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
```

and outside call looks like this:

```
 ParseExcel(@"c:\testfile.xls", conn);
 //cleanup
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Why would you try to do GC cleanup *before* telling the marshalling system that a whole load of COM objects are no longer required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034

Comment: OK, I took the GC calls and put them after my excel method in the outer call.  Still having a lot of memory usage as the program iterates through each cell.  I read something about a hidden range object reference?  Could that be the issue?  I see the GC getting called repeatedly but nothing is reducing the memory/heap.

Comment: I'm snap-shooting the heap and it's growing by like 1MB every few seconds.  It's like every time it moves to a new cell, there's a memory leak.  I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I should not have made my parse method static.  That was the cause of the memory leak.