# my excel application is not releasing from memory in c# windows application in VS 2015

Tags: c#, excel

Everything is working properly but excel application is not releasing from the memory at the end.

```
enter Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile);
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
xlWorkSheet.Cells[9, 5].value = txtqty.Text; 
xlWorkBook.PrintOutEx();
xlWorkBook.Close(false,null,null);
xlApp.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: How do you know it's not releasing memory? Do you see EXCEL.EXE in the process list after this code runs?

Comment: Yes it is showing in task manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code you've posted. I've tried it multiple times and it doesn't keep the process running in the background after the app has been closed.

#### (Possible) Solution

Put your code in a backgroundWorker instance and call the background worker instance asynchronously. This way performing secondary actions won't inhibit the completion of your code.

First add a backgroundWorker instance (Toolbox > Components > background worker) to the form. Secondly add the following code to your form class:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/Projects/Training/MemoryExcelInt/MemoryExcelInt/Example.xlsx");
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[9, 5].value = "ExampleValue";
            xlWorkBook.PrintOutEx();
            xlWorkBook.Close(false, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: After closing the application it is releasing the excel object but if the application is opened and I moved to another form then Excel is in the memory itself. It will create problem

Comment: @SantoshKotwani thanks for giving a bit more information. I've added a hard solution.