# Can't figure out how to close excel process when finished with my program

Tags: c#, excel

I've looked at all the possible answers on stackoverflow and still cant figure out how to solve my problem.

My program creates an excel file, exports data into the file and then should close it. It doesn't close it completely however and the excel process is still running in the background which makes using my code more than once impossible as it always throws up an error.

I start of by creating my excel object

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

I then assign variables to everything I need to use:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

then do all my manipulation.

To close the excel process I use:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\dphillips\Desktop\Projects\C#\Exported Excel File", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

xlWorkBook.Close(true, "Exported Excel File", misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
xlWorkSheet = null;
xlApp = null;
xlWorkBook = null;
```

The process doesn't close though. I used http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm as my template to do this as I'm new to C# and don't have enough experience to do it on my own.

Any advice on how to correctly close the program would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:
Since I can't seem to get any luck with it I will just post my whole program. Maybe then you could tell me exactly where I'm going wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace FormPractice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
            
            //Creating excel object
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;

            //Check to see that excel is installed.
            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }
            
            // regular expressions to check for the ID number in the file and the issue number of the document
            Regex regularExpressionDocID = new Regex(@"\d{3}[A-Z]\W\d{4}\W\d{6}\W\d{3}\W[A-Z]\d{2}");
            Regex regularExpressionIssueNumber = new Regex(@"[i,I]s+(ue)*.?\d{1,2}$");

            var filesToBeRead = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                             .Where(fileNameBeingProcessed =>
                                             (fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".txt")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".docx")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".doc")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".xls")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".pdf")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".docm")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".xlsm")
                                             || fileNameBeingProcessed.EndsWith(".xlsx")))
                                             .ToList();

            var xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            var xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(misValue);
            var xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
            var xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets.get_Item(1);


            string comparingString;
            int counter = 2;

            // setting all headers
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Document Number";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "System Revision";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Revision";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Type";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Old Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "File Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Directory";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Owner";

            foreach (string file in filesToBeRead)
            {
                string documentID, documentName, revision, oldName, directoryOfFile, stringToBeManipulated;
                
                comparingString = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

                Match matchesFormat = regularExpressionDocID.Match(comparingString);
                Match matchesIssue = regularExpressionIssueNumber.Match(comparingString);

                // All manipulations to get each of the required fields for the ARAS upload xlsx
                if (matchesFormat.Success)
                {
                    stringToBeManipulated = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)); // document ID sectiom
                    documentID = stringToBeManipulated.Substring(0, 24);
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 1] = documentID;

                   
                    if (matchesIssue.Success)
                    {
                        //If "issue" is found then gives name(from char [25] and inserts issue into the correct cells
                        revision = matchesIssue.Value;
                        documentName = stringToBeManipulated[25..matchesIssue.Index];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If "issue" is not found fills the issue column with a "-" and makes the entire string the name.
                        revision = "-";
                        documentName = stringToBeManipulated[25..stringToBeManipulated.Length];
                    }
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 2] = documentName;
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 3] = revision;
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 4] = revision;

                    oldName = (Path.GetFileName(file));
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 6] = oldName;
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 7] = oldName;

                    directoryOfFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[counter, 8] = directoryOfFile;
                    counter++;
                }

            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\dphillips\Desktop\Projects\C#\Exported_Old_Doc_ID", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, "Exported Excel File", misValue);
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlApp.Quit();


            //Releasing all objects to stop memory leaks

            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect(); 
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            xlWorkSheet = null;
            xlApp = null;
            xlWorkBook = null;
            xlWorkBooks = null;
            xlWorkSheets = null;



            MessageBox.Show(@"Excel file created , you can find the file C:\Users\dphillips\Desktop\Projects\C#\Directory to pull");

        }
        GC.Collect();
        Close();
```

Comment: Is your process a WPF, Forms or console app (eg it has access to the user's UI)?

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Comment: I use a Form to make it more user friendly. The program prompts the user to browse for a directory they want to import into the excel file and I perform manipulations on the directory to output selected pieces of data from it.

Comment: @sr28 I have read it but I cannot figure out how to convert                 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); away from the double dot.

Comment: 1. Have you set `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;`?  I would do so explicitly before `xlApp.Quit()`.  
2. Check that this isn't just a problem when running under debugger.

Comment: @AlanK I have tried that but unfortunately no success. The excel process is still running in task manager

Comment: You would need to do xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks; Then do the 'Add' on 'xlWorkBooks'. Same principle for xlWorkSheet. Create a variable to store xlWorkBooks.Worksheets first before using it.

Comment: @sr28 I honestly have no idea how to do it. Every time I try change the variable to match  xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks; it tells me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook'

Comment: That's because you've set xlWorkbooks as an Excel.Workbook type. Change that to 'var'.

Comment: Ok, so reading that post again, it actually says the '2 dots rule' is unnecessary and this is the post you should be reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable/25135685#25135685

Comment: @sr28 I understand. When I push the code to release it works fine and the process closes. It really is just a debugger issue. Thank you so much for all your effort in helping me with this