# How to avoid OutOfMemory errors while using excel.range in Interop.Excel

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm programming an application in vb.net (.Net framework >= 4.5) that retrieves data from a database through a web service (as a datatable object) and parses it in an Excel file (unfortunately) with a specific format through the interop library.

The application was working fine but recently I started to get this OutOfMemory error:

Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY)

The error happens when I parse the data from a datatable to an excel.range object (rng) using:

```
rng.value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(DT)
```

The function ConvertDataTableTo2DArray takes a datatable object and returns a 2d array with the information. I've been doing this for a while because it seems to be the fastest way to do this kind of operation (from what I've researched online).

```
        Public Shared Function ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(dataTable As DataTable) As Object(,)
            Dim rows As Integer = dataTable.Rows.Count
            Dim columns As Integer = dataTable.Columns.Count
            Dim dataArray(rows - 1, columns - 1) As Object

            For i As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To columns - 1
                    dataArray(i, j) = dataTable.Rows(i)(j)
                Next
            Next

            Return dataArray
        End Function
```

Consulting other questions posted here and there, I've found out that Excel.Range objects have a limited size, so my initial approach to solving the issue was to divide the datatable by batches of x amount of rows and declare again a new range for each batch. This does not solve the issue at all, so either I'm not clearing the data previously used correctly or the cause of the error is not exactly what I thought it was.

Some additional information:

- I'm working with rows of 22 columns.
- The error seems to happen around row 120.
- I've tried batches of 100, 50 and 20 rows with the same error in the same group of rows (i.e. for 20 row/batch it happened on the 6th batch).
- I'm using a Dell laptop with an I7 and 32GB of RAM. I've checked and the process fails with more than 10 GB of unused RAM.

My code (unfortunately names are in spanish):

```
        Public Shared Sub CopiarDataTableAExcel(dataTable As DataTable, excelHoja As Excel.Worksheet, inicioCelda As String)
            ' Obtener el rango de inicio en base a la celda especificada
            Dim rangoInicio As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range(inicioCelda)

            ' Obtener el rango final en base al tamaño de la DataTable
            Dim rangoFin As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Cells(rangoInicio.Row + dataTable.Rows.Count - 1, rangoInicio.Column + dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)

            ' Obtener el rango completo que abarca desde el inicio hasta el fin
            Dim rangoCompleto As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range(rangoInicio, rangoFin)
            Try
                ' Copiar los datos de la DataTable al rango completo en Excel
                rangoCompleto.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(dataTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Message.Contains("E_OUTOFMEMORY") Then
                    Dim filas_por_particion As Int16 = 20
                    Dim particiones As Int16 = Math.Ceiling(dataTable.Rows.Count / filas_por_particion)
                    For prt = 1 To particiones
                        Dim num_filas As Integer = filas_por_particion
                        If prt = particiones Then
                            num_filas = dataTable.Rows.Count - (prt * filas_por_particion) ' numero de filas menos las filas ya escritas
                        End If
                        'Dim nuevo_rango_inicio As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range("A" & ((prt - 1) * num_filas + 2).ToString)
                        Dim nuevo_rango_inicio As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Cells((prt - 1) * num_filas + 2, 1)
                        Dim nuevo_rango_fin As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Cells(nuevo_rango_inicio.Row + num_filas, nuevo_rango_inicio.Column + dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)

                        Dim nuevo_rango As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range(nuevo_rango_inicio, nuevo_rango_fin)
                        Dim auxDt As DataTable = dataTable.Clone

                        For fila = (prt - 1) * num_filas To prt * num_filas - 1
                            auxDt.ImportRow(dataTable.Rows(fila))
                        Next
                        nuevo_rango.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(auxDt)
                    Next
                Else
                    MsgBox("Se ha producido el siguiente error: " & Chr(13) & ex.Message)
                End If
            End Try
        End Sub
```

In the first section of the code up to `rangoCompleto.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(dataTable)`, you can find my initial approach. In the catch statement, I introduced this "batched" copy that still fails. From my understanding, each declaration of nuevo_rango* variables should clear the previous memory used so the new excel.range, nuevo_rango, should be using a new range with only x (num_filas) amount of rows and 22 columns. while debugging I've checked that my batched data is taking the expected size, that is why I don't understand the OutOfMemory error.

---

UPDATE:

Following @djv's advice and the information in the link he provided, I tried this:

```
        Public Shared Sub CopiarDataTableAExcel(dataTable As DataTable, excelHoja As Excel.Worksheet, inicioCelda As String)
            ' Obtener el rango de inicio en base a la celda especificada
            Dim rangoInicio As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range(inicioCelda)

            ' Obtener el rango final en base al tamaño de la DataTable
            Dim rangoFin As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Cells(rangoInicio.Row + dataTable.Rows.Count - 1, rangoInicio.Column + dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)

            ' Obtener el rango completo que abarca desde el inicio hasta el fin
            Dim rangoCompleto As Excel.Range = excelHoja.Range(rangoInicio, rangoFin)
            Try
                ' Copiar los datos de la DataTable al rango completo en Excel
                rangoCompleto.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(dataTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Message.Contains("E_OUTOFMEMORY") Then
                    Dim filas_por_particion As Int16 = 100
                    Dim particiones As Int16 = Math.Ceiling(dataTable.Rows.Count / filas_por_particion)
                    For prt = 1 To particiones
                        Dim num_filas As Integer = filas_por_particion
                        If prt = particiones Then
                            num_filas = (prt * filas_por_particion) - dataTable.Rows.Count ' numero de filas menos las filas ya escritas
                        End If
                        DT2Excel(excelHoja, num_filas, prt, dataTable)
                        GC.Collect()
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
                    Next
                Else
                    MsgBox("Se ha producido el siguiente error: " & Chr(13) & ex.Message)
                End If
            End Try
        End Sub


        Public Shared Function DT2Excel(exl As Excel.Worksheet, num_filas As Int16, num_iter As Int16, dt As DataTable) As Boolean

            Try
                Dim rng_inicio As New Tuple(Of Int16, Int16)((num_iter - 1) * num_filas + 2, 1)
                Dim nuevo_rango_inicio As Excel.Range = exl.Cells(rng_inicio.Item1, rng_inicio.Item2)
                Dim rng_fin As New Tuple(Of Int16, Int16)(nuevo_rango_inicio.Row + num_filas, nuevo_rango_inicio.Column + dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                Dim nuevo_rango_fin As Excel.Range = exl.Cells(rng_fin.Item1, rng_fin.Item2)

                Dim nuevo_rango As Excel.Range = exl.Range(nuevo_rango_inicio, nuevo_rango_fin)
                Dim auxDt As DataTable = dt.Clone

                For fila = (num_iter - 1) * num_filas To num_iter * num_filas - 1
                    auxDt.ImportRow(dt.Rows(fila))
                Next
                nuevo_rango.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(auxDt)
                nuevo_rango = Nothing
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try

        End Function
```

It no longer throws an error but it is still not copying after row 104. I even encapsulated the part using the ranges inside another function to avoid the noted debugging errors but I feel like that will only work if I encapsulate **all** the Excel objects, which would defeat the purpose of the function.

It seems like the Excel.range object is still not freeing memory... I guess I could instantiate the workbook and open the file in every iteration but that defeats the purpose of doing the operation fast.

Comment: At the end of each iteration, set your range to Nothing, then call `GC.Collect()`, `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/832052)

Comment: I followed the tips given in the answer but it is not working properly. It no longer throws an error but it is still not copying after row 104. I even encapsulated the part using the ranges inside another function to avoid the noted debugging errors. It seems like the Excel.range object is still not freeing memory... I guess I could instantiate the workbook and open the file in every iteration but that defeats the purpose of doing the operation fast.

Comment: Update your question to show how you're releasing the objects.

Comment: @djv just updated it!

Comment: @Roc *don't* use Interop at all. Use a library like EPPlus or ClosedXML to load the data directly into a real Excel file without using Excel itself. Your entire code can be reduced to a [single call to LoadFromDataTable](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromDataTable), with headers and styling, eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt,true,TableStyles.Dark1)`

Comment: `Excel.Range objects have a limited size` I don't know what you mean or where you found that. A single Excel sheet can have up to 1M rows, not just 100, but the code you use is excruciatingly slow. Every single object and method call is a slow cross-process call to another process. Every Excel object you use is yet another long-lived COM object that has to be released.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your insight, I'm aware that interop is trash and I'm ultimately trying to avoid using Excel in general. Right now I don't have much time to allocate to the migration to those libraries, but which one do you think has better performance/complexity ratio? I've read that ClosedXML has great performance but is more complex to manage.
I've read it in other stackoverflow posts (I'll try to find it) and I think the Error and the behavior of the code show that the range has no space to allocate that much data.
I don't understand how GC is not releasing those COM obj

Comment: @Roc "...I don't have much time to allocate to the migration to those libraries" How much time would it take to add a reference and create one function with Panagiotis' one line of code, versus trying to continue to debug this issue?

Comment: Hey @HardCode, it had to do more with maintaining multiple apps, software licenses and other issues. Ultimately, I switched from interop for most operations but I'm afraid that there are some cases where interop is the only option I've found, like managing files in Sharepoint. I guess I could always perform a local copy and keep using those libraries, but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to release the ranges inside the function

```vb
Public Shared Function DT2Excel(exl As Excel.Worksheet, num_filas As Int16, num_iter As Int16, dt As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim nuevo_rango_inicio As Excel.Range
    Dim nuevo_rango_fin As Excel.Range
    Dim nuevo_rango As Excel.Range
    Try
        Dim rng_inicio As New Tuple(Of Int16, Int16)((num_iter - 1) * num_filas + 2, 1)
        nuevo_rango_inicio = exl.Cells(rng_inicio.Item1, rng_inicio.Item2)

        Dim rng_fin As New Tuple(Of Int16, Int16)(nuevo_rango_inicio.Row + num_filas, nuevo_rango_inicio.Column + dt.Columns.Count - 1)
        nuevo_rango_fin = exl.Cells(rng_fin.Item1, rng_fin.Item2)

        nuevo_rango = exl.Range(nuevo_rango_inicio, nuevo_rango_fin)

        Dim auxDt As DataTable = dt.Clone

        For fila = (num_iter - 1) * num_filas To num_iter * num_filas - 1
            auxDt.ImportRow(dt.Rows(fila))
        Next
        nuevo_rango.Value = ConvertDataTableTo2DArray(auxDt)
        
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        nuevo_rango = Nothing
        nuevo_rango_inicio = Nothing
        nuevo_rango_fin = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End Try

End Function
```

It may not matter. Exiting the function should release the references and the GC should handle it properly, but it's worth a try.

Also inside the method `CopiarDataTableAExcel` in the For loop, do the same. Use a `Finally` block to clear the references and GC. It's a little odd though, that you are seemingly doing the actual work in an exception handler after an out of memory exception.

Comment: Hey djv, no luck. It seems like adding the ```finally``` statement did not help.

Comment: @Roc why are you doing work inside the out of memory exception handler in the first place?

Comment: because I'm unaware of the maximum size I can use for the range and I rather handle it iteratively than determine the size of the range. I have no knowledge of how memory is allocated for each cell, if it changes with the data type, and so on, so I devised this solution to chop all the range into other smaller ranges and make the function extremely flexible. My intention is to make it work with any excel sheet.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation and the same error. It turned out some of the data elements started with the `=` character, and this was causing the out of memory error. I fixed it by adding an apostrophe `'` to the start of those strings before writing them to excel. E.g. `=sample_text` becomes `'=sample_text`. This way Excel doesn't attempt to interpret them as formulas, but as normal text strings instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).