# C# Excel Border Left and Right

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, border

I want to create border on a cell and then a left and right border.

I tried this code but it doesnt work:(

```
objSheet.get_Range("F19").Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = true;
objSheet.get_Range("F19").Borders.Color = Color.Black;
```

I get the second one you see here. (A border all around) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Ujy.png

How can I get this working? Or is a border at the left and right side of a cell not possible from C# to Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var range = objSheet.get_Range("F19");
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Color = color;
range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Color = color;
```

Edit: If you're worried about cleaning up your Excel objects and you want to avoid using two dots ([see discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)), you can keep a reference the the borders that you use like so:

```
var right = range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight];
var left = range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft];
right.Color = color;
left.Color = color;
```

I think my original version indirectly uses two dots.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the line style and colour for specific borders like this:

```
Excel.Range range = objSheet.get_Range("F19");
Excel.Border border = range.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight];
border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border.Color = Color.Black;

border = range.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft];
border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border.Color = Color.Black;
```

And then clean up your references:

```
border = null;
range = null;
```

Specifically creating a reference to the `Excel.Border` object ensures you can dispose of it and won't leave it hanging around. See [Eliminating use of '2 dots' when using Excel...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13069755/976080)