# (Final)ReleaseComObject doesn't release file lock by COM object

Tags: c#, vb.net

When using the following code:

```
Dim modiDocument As New MODI.Document
modiDocument.Create(TifFile)
modiDocument.Close(False)
```

Then the TifFile isn't locked and I can do things like e.g. delete it (IO.File.Delete).

However when I enumerate the Images then the file will be locked:

```
Dim modiDocument As New MODI.Document
modiDocument.Create(TifFile)
For Each modiImage In modiDocument.Images
  'Doesn't matter if I enter code here or not.
Next
modiDocument.Close(False)
```

Now the file will be locked.

I tried everything (I think) to solve this, like:

```
Dim modiDocument As New MODI.Document
modiDocument.Create(TifFile)
For Each modiImage In modiDocument.Images
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(modiImage)
Next
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(modiImage)
modiDocument.Close(False)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(modiDocument)
```

Yes, I also tried FinalReleaseComObject.

So far, no luck.

How can I solve this?

NB: The example here are in VB. I also know C#, so it doesn't matter in which language you provide code examples.

Comment: `FinalReleaseComObject` calls `ReleaseComObject` in a loop til it's released, it maybe more times than 3 times. So you should try `FinalReleaseComObject`

Comment: I tried that without result

Comment: There is an enumerator object that you cannot see, probably IEnumVariant.  This is in general why it is such a bad idea to try to implement manual memory management, the syntax sugar in VB.NET and C# give you far too much rope to hang yourself.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191489/releasing-temporary-com-objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to release every COM object you instantiate, and it's very easy to miss one.  E.g. you have missed `modiDocument.Images`.

The following may help:

```
modiDocument.Create(TifFile)
var images = modiDocument.Images
For Each modiImage In images
    ...
Next
...
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(images)
```

If you add code in the For Each loop that instantiates additional COM objects, they'll need to be cleaned up too.